# Passing new data to variable is giving me error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set up a simple geofence. It works fine if I add the lat and long without `''`. So if I add an updated variable it does not seem to load correctly. Its hard to explain but if I run it like so it works

```
var distance;

var job_p_lat = 52.407580;
var job_p_lng = -1.486180;

var my_lat = 52.414493799999995;
var my_lng = -1.5574936;

distance = calculateDistance(my_lat, my_lng, job_p_lat, job_p_lng)
$("#distance").text(distance);

if (distance < .05) {
  $("#message").text("Yes, were inside .05 KM!!! :) A+")
} else if (distance > .05) {
  $("#message").text("No, not inside .05 KM :(")
}
```

But if I change the data like so it does not seem to load it correctly?

```
var job_p_lat = '52.407580';
var job_p_lng = '-1.486180';

var my_lat = '52.414493799999995';
var my_lng = '-1.5574936';
```

The distance calculator code is :

```
function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var R = 5550; // km
  var dLat = (lat2 - lat1).toRad();
  var dLon = (lon2 - lon1).toRad();
  var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) *
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c;
  return d;
}

Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
  return this * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: lat1.toRad is not a function at calculateDistance (scriptnew3.1.js:442) at initsuccess (scriptnew3.1.js:175)

Really can't seem to work out what the problem is?

Comment: can you write your error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: lat1.toRad is not a function
    at calculateDistance (scriptnew3.1.js:442)
    at initsuccess (scriptnew3.1.js:175)

Comment: where is the `toRad` function declared?

Comment: in the calculateDistance function. Thats not the problem, the problem is with the '' i think?

Comment: If you have the `toRad()` function, then it's probably part of the Number prototype. You are passing a string, so that doesn't have the `toRad()` function. Try to convert your string to a number first.

Comment: Have you tryed double quotes? simple quotes turns it to string. And once it's a string you can't performe math operations. You would need to use parseFloat

Comment: @Ivar comment is an answer.

Comment: No beacuse its reading the new variable from a text input like so :   var my_lat = document.getElementById('my_lat').value;
  var my_lng = document.getElementById('my_lng').value;

Comment: @larrychambers then it will be a string need to convert to a number and then to a radian, I think so otherwise, I need to see more keenly.

Comment: @larrychambers I don't know when the down vote occurred but if it's before you added your error message, that could be the reason. But only the person who down voted can tell you why they did. That being said, if your question got answered, [make sure to accept the answer that helped you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: its not yet, i am working on it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It gets interpreted as a string if you add quotes around it. If you want to work with it as an int you will have to convert it to an int.

lat.parseInt() or lat.parseFloat() would work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was possible with:

```
function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var R = 3958.7558657440545; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180;  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
  var a = 
     0.5 - Math.cos(dLat)/2 + 
     Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) * 
     (1 - Math.cos(dLon))/2;

  return R * 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you changed and why this fixes your problem. Also thanking for down votes is not part of an answer, so it doesn't belong to your answer. It often even has the opposite effect.